# A confusing structure: verb+ing as ... do

Tags: meaning-in-context, inversion, as

I came across a confusing structure from Arthur Schopenhauer. Here is the text:

> Fichte, Schelling, and Hegel are not philosophers, **lacking as they do**
> the first requisite for being counted as such: seriousness and honesty
> of research

The tricky part for me is the bold part, namely, "lacking as they do". As far as I understand the meaning is that: Fichte, Schelling, and Hegel are not philosophers, **as (meaning because) they lack the first (...)**. Therefore it seems to me that there is a kind of unusual structure than standard. Because instead of saying "as they lack" the writer said "lacking as they do". Then I have two questions:

1. Is the meaning that I understand right?
2. What is called this different structure?

Comment: It's called 'inversion for emphasis'. 'Lacking as they do' is stronger than 'as they lack'.

Comment: Hegel isn't a philosopher, huh? That's certainly a bold claim!

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Thank you so much, Michael. I will research this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, that is what Schopenhauer always does, complaining :)

Comment: Also he wrote in German, so your text must be someone's translation.